# In react hooks, How can I delay onInput event till I have finished typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I currently have an input field that is meant to trigger an api call when an 11 digit number is input. How do I delay it from making the call until all 11 digits are typed

Comment: When the length of the input is equal to 11 (check if they are all digits) and send the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like this should do the trick.

```js
const callAPI = (value) =>{
    if(value.length === 11){
    console.log("Call API")
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="callAPI(value)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the component be a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), and perform the check to trigger the API call in the input's change handler.

Here is a code sample.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    if (inputValue.length === 11) {
      // code to trigger API call
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
  );
}
```

**Explanation:**

A controlled component controls the value of the input element using the React state itself.

1. Import the state hook.

   `import { useState } from 'react';`
2. Use a state hook for the input's value.

   `const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(0);`
3. Set the input's value attribute to equal to the state.

   `<input value={inputValue} />`
4. Add an `onChange` event handler to the input element.

   `<input value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />`
5. Create the event handler.

   `const handleChange = (e) => { //code for event handler }`

   Whenever you type in the input field, this will trigger the `onChange` event and run the event handler `handleChange`.
6. In the event handler, first update the state using the user input.

   `setInputValue(e.target.value);`
7. Then, check the length of the input value, and trigger the call accordingly.

   `if (inputValue.length === 11) { // code to trigger API call }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a controlled form it is easy to check when you update the value.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Form() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  function handelChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
    // If the length is 11 characters do something
    if (inputValue.length === 11) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else {
      // Otherwise do something else
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  }

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(e) => {
        handelChange(e);
      }}
      value={inputValue}
    />
  );
}
```